# How to filter files from the Last modified date

Tags: node.js

I need to know how can i mention "filter" the files per date for example files of day: 2 until 12.

```
const fs = require('fs');

const testFolder = 'C:/Users/duff/Downloads/xmlpath/';

fs.readdirSync(testFolder).forEach(file => {  //Reading files from folder

        fs.stat(testFolder+file,'utf8', function(err,data){

      console.log(data.mtime); // print the last modified date
    }
    );
  });
```

I've tried with this code but i get all files dates without filtering them

[result of files dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNFej.png)

Comment: You could look into using [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to convert the timestamps in your screenshot to [Unix timestamps](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/) which are purely numerical values in milliseconds since Jan 1st, 1970. This potentially might make sorting easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think what you want to do is provide a date range and return the files within that range.

I'm stripping the hours and making comparison against the dates here

```
const fs = require('fs')

const testFolder = './test'

const parseDate = timestamp => new Date(timestamp).toISOString().slice(0, 10)

const handler = async (f, t) => {
    const startDate = parseDate(f)
    const endDate = parseDate(t)

    const timestamp = file => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            fs.stat(`${testFolder}/${file}`, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
                if (err) return reject(err)
                return resolve({ filename: `${testFolder}/${file}`, date: parseDate(data.mtime) })
            })
        })
    }

    const timestamps = await Promise.all(fs.readdirSync(testFolder).map(timestamp))

    return timestamps.filter(({ date }) => date >= startDate && date <= endDate)
}

handler('2020-04-01', '2020-04-10')
```

This will then produce an array of objects like so

```
[ { filename: 'C:/Users/duff/Downloads/xmlpath/test1', date: '2020-04-09' },
  { filename: 'C:/Users/duff/Downloads/xmlpath/hello', date: '2020-04-09' },
  { filename: 'C:/Users/duff/Downloads/xmlpath/new', date: '2020-04-10' },
  { filename: 'C:/Users/duff/Downloads/xmlpath/yes', date: '2020-04-10' } ]
```

Comment: Thanks man! really helpful i was getting frustrated here. but i'm trying here to compare the same date like:handler('2020-04-11', '2020-04-11') and results all array range. What'd I do wrong? @razki

Comment: No issues! Ah you want the time rather than the date? - Sorry I must've misread your question if that's the case

Comment: No, it is exactly what was trying to do. really good your method. Now when I put the same date of the day like '2020-04-11' the array return the past files of that date too like '2020-04-10', '2020-04-09' & '2020-04-08'.---> [Image](https://imgur.com/a/wAnUC05) – Wander Pereira da Silva

Answer (score -1):

This is how with some additional stuff where i am saving files and retrieving the final file :

```
router.post("/download", function (req, res) {
  var yourscript = exec("./export.sh", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    console.log(stdout);
    console.log(stderr);
  });

  function downloadLatestFile() {
    const dirPath = "/Users/tarekhabche/Desktop/awsTest/reports";
    const lastFile = JSON.stringify(getMostRecentFile(dirPath));
    fileDate = lastFile.substr(14, 19);
    console.log(fileDate);
    const fileToDownload = `reports/info.${fileDate}.csv`;
    console.log(fileToDownload);
    res.download(fileToDownload);
  }
  setTimeout(function () {
    downloadLatestFile();
  }, 1000);
});

const getMostRecentFile = (dir) => {
  const files = orderRecentFiles(dir);
  return files.length ? files[0] : undefined;
};

const orderRecentFiles = (dir) => {
  return fs
    .readdirSync(dir)
    .filter((file) => fs.lstatSync(path.join(dir, file)).isFile())
    .map((file) => ({ file, mtime: fs.lstatSync(path.join(dir, file)).mtime }))
    .sort((a, b) => b.mtime.getTime() - a.mtime.getTime());
};

const dirPath = "reports";
getMostRecentFile(dirPath);
```